# GAE clear database

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an error in my datastore that stops me from viewing it via the console. I want to delete the whole datastore and start again.

The following works on the development server:

```
db.delete(db.Query(keys_only=True))
```

When I run the same on the remote sever I get the following error (and the datastore is not cleared)

```
    illegal key.path.element.type: __Stat_PropertyType_PropertyName_Kind__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~34thquote/1.360465535514332795/core/handlers/quotes.py", line 72, in get
    db.delete(db.Query(keys_only=True))
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1610, in delete
    delete_async(models, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 815, in get_result
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1653, in __delete_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1216, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: illegal key.path.element.type: __Stat_PropertyType_PropertyName_Kind__
```

Comment: This error occurs because you're trying to delete some of the reserved entity kinds, which are used for datastore statistics. See Dan's answer for the best way to clear the datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete all the entities of a certain kind (or all kinds), the easiest way is to use [datastore_admin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin), which is enabled in your live application's admin console.